# Train your own CycleGAN style translator

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I have a set of images (a few hundred) that represent a certain style and I would like to train an [unpaired image to image translator with CycleGAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10593).

**I'm looking for a tutorial on how one would do this with `NetTrain`.**

For example, in the Wolfram Neural Net repository there is a [NetModel for Photo-to-Van Gogh Translation](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/CycleGAN-Monet-to-Photo-Translation), but the construction notebook is missing any details about training:

[image]

Ok, so I'm trying to piece this back the missing training section. From the construction notebook we have these functions:

```
convIN[args___] := {ConvolutionLayer[args], 
  InstanceNormalizationLayer["Epsilon" -> 0.00001]}

convINRamp[args___] := {ConvolutionLayer[args], 
  InstanceNormalizationLayer["Epsilon" -> 0.00001], 
  ElementwiseLayer[Ramp]}

residualModule = NetGraph[
   {
    NetChain@
     Join[{PaddingLayer[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}, 
        "Padding" -> "Reflected"]}, 
      convINRamp[128, 
       3], {PaddingLayer[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}, 
        "Padding" -> "Reflected"]}, convIN[128, 3]],
    TotalLayer[]
    },
   {NetPort["Input"] -> {1, 2}, 1 -> 2}
   ];

cycleGAN = NetChain[
  Join[
   {ElementwiseLayer[2 # - 1 &],
    PaddingLayer[{{0, 0}, {3, 3}, {3, 3}}, 
     "Padding" -> "Reflected"]},
   convINRamp[32, 7],
   convINRamp[64, 3, "PaddingSize" -> 1, "Stride" -> 2],
   convINRamp[128, 3, "PaddingSize" -> 1, "Stride" -> 2],
   ConstantArray[residualModule, 9],
   {DeconvolutionLayer[64, 3, "Stride" -> 2],
    PartLayer[{All, 2 ;;, 2 ;;}],
    InstanceNormalizationLayer["Epsilon" -> 0.00001],
    ElementwiseLayer[Ramp],
    DeconvolutionLayer[32, 3, "Stride" -> 2],
    PartLayer[{All, 2 ;;, 2 ;;}],
    InstanceNormalizationLayer["Epsilon" -> 0.00001],
    ElementwiseLayer[Ramp],
    PaddingLayer[{{0, 0}, {3, 3}, {3, 3}}, "Padding" -> "Reflected"],
    ConvolutionLayer[3, 7],
    ElementwiseLayer[0.5*Tanh[#] + 0.5 &]}
   ],
  "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", 512}],
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Image"}]
  ]
```

Now let's grab some data in order to try training it:

```
styleFolder = "~/Downloads/style";
randomFolder = "~/Downloads/random";

CreateDirectory /@ {styleFolder, randomFolder};

URLDownload[#, styleFolder] & /@ 
  WebImageSearch["monet", "ImageHyperlinks", "MaxItems" -> 5];

URLDownload[#, randomFolder] & /@ 
  WebImageSearch["outdoors", "ImageHyperlinks", "MaxItems" -> 5];

styleImages = File /@ FileNames["*.jpg", styleFolder]
randomImages = File /@ FileNames["*.jpg", randomFolder]
```

This is where I'm stuck, and there are two main questions:

1. How to write cycle-consistency loss
2. How to format/feed the training data to the GAN

But I'm still a long way from filling in these last two lines:

```
trainingData = (* ? *)
NetTrain[cycleGAN, trainingData]
```

**Links:**

- The code and full results for the CycleGAN paper can be viewed at https://github.com/junyanz/

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say NetTrain was never meant to support GAN training, maybe this will be a future feature in v11.4 or v12?

Comment: @M.R. this is true, NetTrain is not designed for GANs. Generalizing NetTrain to support GANs and reinforcement learning is a high priority for us for the next version.

Comment: @Sebastian So do you train the CycleGAN based NetModels in pure MXNet?

Comment: @user5601: We've never trained CycleGANs. But yes, you could train it in MXNet for now.

Comment: @user5601 see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141277/42578

Comment: The mnist example doesn't simply extend to this

Comment: If no one can get this to work in v12 I’m giving up on Mma for ML, this is trivial in pytorch!!

Comment: I added a bounty, hopefully that will help you @user5601

Comment: I believe this is not supported in 12.0 either.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a complete CycleGAN construction example in the Mathematica 12.1 documentation for [NetGANOperator](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetGANOperator.html) (under Applications)

Comment: the example you're referring to has very little to do with actual CycleGAN implementation as originally asked: everything is wrong from loss function to the training logic. 

It's actually impossible to recreate original CycleGAN in NetTrain settings (and even using undocumented MXNetLink functionality.


MMA up to 13 is not suitable for nontrivial GANs and I suspect this will never change.