# Using Non-Negative Matrix Factorization (NNMF)

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to understand NNMF (Non-Negative Matrix Factorization). This is not a built-in function in Mathematica, but there is a package that implements it, which is refered to in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114565/1783). The package is loaded by:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/NonNegativeMatrixFactorization.m"]
```

The problem that NNMF tries to solve is this: given a matrix $X$, factor it as $W.H$ where $W$ and $H$ both have all positive entries.

But when I try to apply this using the package, I cannot figure out what is happening. First, construct a matrix $x$ -- I build it random, but of low rank (rank 5):

```
xKer = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {5, 5}];
xL = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {50, 5}];
xR = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {5, 100}];
x = xL.xKer.xR;
Dimensions[x]
MatrixRank[x]
```

So you can see $x$ is 50 by 100, but is of rank only 5. Applying the NNMF command from the package:

```
{w, h} = GDCLS[x, 5, "MaxSteps" -> 1000];
Dimensions[w]
Dimensions[h]
```

So we can see that $w.h$ has the same dimensions as $x$. But

```
Norm[w.h - x]
```

is very large, so $w.h$ is not a good approximation to $x$.

Thus my questions: why doesn't NNMF seem to work? Am I expecting the wrong thing?

Comment: Maybe `x` simply cannot be factored this way?  Moreover, it is more realistic to condsider a relative error measure. E.g., `Norm[w.h - x, "Frobenius"]/Norm[x, "Frobenius"]` returns `0.00326206` which is not _that_ bad... With `MaxSteps -> 10000`, one can get down to `0.00075928` or so.

Comment: If you create x = xL.xR then it for sure *can* be expressed as w.h, and there is still significant error in the Norm. But maybe you are right, the error is small compared to the size of x.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher beat me to it! (BTW, the automatic precision goal is 4.)

Comment: "This is not a built-in function in Mathematica, but there is a package that implements it [...]" -- see the implementation and documentation ["NonNegativeMatrixFactorization"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NonNegativeMatrixFactorization) published 12 days ago at [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/).

Answer (score 7):

Thank you for using that package!

The stopping criteria is based on relative precision. Find the lines:

```
 ....
 normV = Norm[V, "Frobenius"]; diffNorm = 10 normV;
 If[ pgoal === Automatic, pgoal = 4 ];      
 While[nSteps < maxSteps && TrueQ[! NumberQ[pgoal] || NumberQ[pgoal] && (normV > 0) && diffNorm/normV > 10^(-pgoal)],
   nSteps++;
   ...
```

in [the implementation code](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/NonNegativeMatrixFactorization.m). Note the condition `diffNorm/normV > 10^(-pgoal)`.

Here is an example based on question’s code:

```
SeedRandom[2343]
xKer = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {5, 5}];
xL = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {50, 5}];
xR = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {5, 100}];
x = xL.xKer.xR;
Dimensions[x]
MatrixRank[x]

(* {50, 100} *)

(* 5 *)

Options[GDCLS]

(* {"MaxSteps" -> 200, "NonNegative" -> True, 
 "Epsilon" -> 1.*10^-9, "RegularizationParameter" -> 0.01, 
 PrecisionGoal -> Automatic, "PrintProfilingInfo" -> False} *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 {w, h} = GDCLS[x, 5, PrecisionGoal -> 3, "MaxSteps" -> 100000];
 {Dimensions[w], Dimensions[h]}
]

(* {19.759, {{50, 5}, {5, 100}}} *)

Norm[w.h - x]/Norm[x]

(* 0.000939317 *)
```

Comment: This algorithm seems to be a bit slow. 100000 iterations is quite a lot. I am pretty sure that one can make a [semi-smooth Newton method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176048) with much higher convergence rate work for the underlying optimization problem. If you like, I can elaborate on this. Are you interested?

Comment: Thanks for writing the package! And of course, thanks also for helping me understand how to use it. I am hoping to replace some SVD calculations with NNMF.

Comment: @bills Thanks, good to hear! You might be also interested in Independent Component Analysis (ICA) discussed (together with NNMF) in MSE's question ["How to do Independent Component Analysis?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/106047/34008), and the Community posts ["Independent component analysis for multidimensional signals"](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/861508) and ["Comparison of dimension reduction algorithms over mandala images generation"](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1011591).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher **1)** Yes, this NNMF implementation is slow and NNMF should be fast (enough) since it is usually run several times, since NNMF is prone to go into local minima. **2)** "100000 iterations is quite a lot." -- I mostly use NNMF to NLP (topic extraction) and I rarely run NNMF more than 12-20 steps. **3)** Of course, all improvement suggestions are welcome. I would say, it would be best if you write a package and post it in GitHub.